# UML class diagram - Method from other classes - Which connector?

Tags: class, uml, diagram

I have a bunch of separated PHP classes. They have nothing special, no constants, just normal variables. The only connection between them are the call of methods.

Is there a way to model this connection in the UML class diagram? I guessed that it would be the "association" with a -> arrow

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. If `A2` has a reference to `B2` (i.e., using a "normal variable"), you write the name of that variable at the end of the association, nearest to the arrowhead pointing to `B2`. If that variable references a collection of `B2s`, you ignore the intervening collection type and make the multiplicity [0..*].